# Initializer syntax vs. parameterless constructor syntax

Tags: c#, list, initializer

There are two alternative styles of instantiating a new empty "list" -style object:

```
var list = new SomeListType<int>();
```

or

```
var list = new SomeListType<int> { };
```

The first relies on allowing the basic constructor to setup the object, the second would seem to also implicitly rely on the constructor, but also specifies an empty initializer list.

(The intializer list being left empty on purpose, say if it seemed to be more readable or clearer in some context.)

*Is there any practical or functional difference between these two approaches?*

<sub>(Note -- `SomeListType` could be anything that can be constructed like this - such as a standard `List<T>` or some custom class. Using `int` just for example).</sub>

Comment: Chose whatever you find more readable. There's no other difference. Both will use the default constructor. The latter will call `Add` for every item in the `{}`. Since it's empty there's no difference.

Comment: tip: if you ever want to see the real differences between two lines of code: sharplab.io - [here's this example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmAAgGUB7MOAGTVgBUBPABzgB4aA+AkAnARgBYAdFVisOAbwC+AWABQOAMzdCAYQJjZBTd0U4+BAIIAKAJRqNWiwDcICAhmowCAXgIA7OAHdiZSg/pNmNFcYNhMAbnNNaRkLBW49ACETMxiLLWtbe1hnN09vcmEYfxYgkLUCCQjUqNkJIA==) - look at either the IL results (note that `A` and `B` are identical except for the name), or the C# results if it is something non-trivial that has interesting C# generated code (async, expressions, iterators, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Even the generated IL code will be the same for both options:

```
newobj instance void class Namespace.SomeListType`1<int32>::.ctor()
```

So there is no functional difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

The two lines you have written will compile the same. The difference is that in the second version you can initialize the list by adding items in the curly braces (provided your lists implements the `ICollection<T>` interface or provides a respective `Add` method:

```
var list = new SomeListType<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: The type just needs to implement `IEnumerable` acc. to [specs](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/f12213c4ffe77a51dbc5412250bef6af75333f32/expressions.md#collection-initializers).

Comment: @MarcGravell: of course, but Sefe has said that it needs to implement `ICollection<T>`

Comment: Why would it need to implement IEnumerable to add items to it? (I know it has to but why)

Comment: @Magnus: because that is what the language expects as minimum to support the syntactic sugar feature to call `Add` automatically if you use `{item1,item2}`. It needs to be an `IEnumerable` and it needs to have an `Add` method(can be an extension).